# How to set time according to svg length?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am learning javascript and react and here I am stuck in the challange that where I have to set time according to SVG image's length (something like progress bar).

For an ease and basic example, I am calculating total time of 24 hours in 1440 minutes  and I have given passed time `let passedMins = 1220`

Now I need to fill the green line in svg circle according to the time elapse. Like every minute green line should add up more

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from 'react';

function Clock(props) {

  useEffect(() => {
    const circle = document.querySelector('circle');
    const circleLength = Math.floor(circle.getTotalLength());
    const perMinArea = circleLength / 1440;
    let passedMins = 1220;
    const fillArea = passedMins * perMinArea;
    circle.style.strokeDasharray = circleLength - fillArea;
    // circle.style.strokeDashoffset = circleLength -fillArea;

  }, [props.time])

  return (
    <div className = "clock-space" >
      <div className = "clock" >{props.time}</div>
      <svg width = "130" height = "130" className = "circle" viewBox = "0 0 130 130" fill = "none" xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="65" cy="65" r="61.5" stroke="lightgreen" strokeWidth="7"/>
      </svg>
    </div >
  );
}

export default Clock;
```

It looks like this:

[image: Image of circle]

It shows 3 lines where I want only one. Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: What exactyl do you mean from _"fill the svg circle according to the time passed"_? What are you trying to achieve? Your code produces similar result to the image you posted.

Comment: Yes @GeomanYabes the result that it is producing in the image is to fix... there are three lines where I want only one line which fills up the circumference as each minute is passed like what happen in progress bars

Comment: doesn't it come from the chosen style ? `strokeDasharray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also pass the length of the circle to the `circle.style.strokeDasharray`. To do this, you need to get the length for the "minutes left" in terms of the circle's total length. Please see example below.

```js
const circle = document.querySelector('circle');
const timeLeftLabel = document.getElementById('time-left');
const circleLength = Math.floor(circle.getTotalLength());
const maxMinutes = 1440;
let passedMins = 1220;
let minsLeft = maxMinutes - passedMins;

// get percentage of minutes left
let minsLeftPercentage = minsLeft / maxMinutes;

// x % of length where x  = minsLeftPercentage
let leftLength = minsLeftPercentage * circleLength;

//combine leftLength and circleLength into comma-separated string
circle.style.strokeDasharray = leftLength + ',' + circleLength;

//just simple implementation for the {props.time} 
timeLeftLabel.innerText = minsLeft + ' minutes left';
```

```html
<div className="clock-space">
  <div className="clock" id="time-left"></div>
  <svg width="130" height="130" className="circle" viewBox="0 0 130 130" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="65" cy="65" r="61.5" stroke="lightgreen" strokeWidth="7"/>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Geoman Yabes, lol I missed a simple thing to put array values in strokeDashArray...

`circle.style.strokeDasharray = (circleLength - fillArea) + "," + circleLength;` this fixed it. Thanks again

Comment: @punit-doc, glad I helped. marked it as the answer if you feel it is.

Comment: I don't know. I have already accepted you both guy's answers but it doesnt keep saved

Answer (score -1):

You could use a second circle (maybe with an id "mask") to cover the green stroke. The green one should have no dasharray. Then you would change the stroke-dashoffset for the mask. In my simple animate() test (without react) it ran from 0 to -390 (circlelength). The stroke color for #mask (here for testing white) should be the one from your background...

```
const circle = document.querySelector('#mask');
const maxMins = 1440;
...
  circle.style.strokeDasharray = maxMins;
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = maxMins - circleLength + fillArea;
...
<circle cx="65" cy="65" r="61.5" stroke="lightgreen" strokeWidth="7"/>
<circle id="mask" cx="65" cy="65" r="61.5" stroke="white" strokeWidth="7"/>
```

Working example (here with "timelapse" and reset of passedMins):

```js
    const circle = document.querySelector('#mask');
    const circleLength = Math.floor(circle.getTotalLength());
    const maxMins = 1440;
      const perMinArea = circleLength / maxMins;
    let passedMins = 0;
      circle.style.strokeDasharray = maxMins;
      circle.style.strokeDashoffset = maxMins - circleLength;
    
    setInterval( function() {
        passedMins = (passedMins == maxMins) ? 0 : passedMins + 3;
        
        const fillArea = passedMins * perMinArea;
        circle.style.strokeDashoffset = maxMins - circleLength + fillArea;
    }, 10);
```

```html
    <div className="clock-space">
        <div className="clock" id="time-left"></div>
        <svg width="130" height="130" className="circle" viewBox="0 0 130 130" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <circle cx="65" cy="65" r="61.5" stroke="lightgreen" strokeWidth="7"/>
            <circle id="mask" cx="65" cy="65" r="61.5" stroke="white" strokeWidth="7"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: This didn't answer the OP's question.